# Yes I am dark ! Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I can roar but I have no mouth,

I can cry but I have no eyes,

I am good, but bad sometimes.

> And without me.. you all die..

Who am I ?

Comment: doesn't the title say who you are? :p

Comment: that's part of riddle. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might be

> A rain cloud

I can roar but I have no mouth

> Referring to thunder

I can cry but I have no eyes

> Referring to rain

I am good, but bad sometimes.

> Rain clouds are required but can turn into storms.

Comment: "And without me.. you all die.." poor guys in sunny cities...

Comment: that was quick.. Will accept the answer after sometime :)

Answer (score 5):

You might be

> Air

I can roar but I have no mouth

> Wind

I can cry but I have no eyes

> Moisture

I am good, but bad sometimes.

> Hurricanes

And without me.. you all die..

> Ofcourse Air (O2)

Comment: Good one, but does not suite the title, **I am dark!**

Comment: Hate to be a pedant but air is more than just O2. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

I can roar but I have no mouth,

I can cry but I have no eyes,

I am good, but bad sometimes.

And without me.. you all die..

Who am I ?

Answer is:

> I guess water it's because water has roaring sounds when ocean waves are enough strong.water has crying sound when dripping and of course tsunami and floods make it  bad.  And no doubt without water survival is next to impossible.

Comment: I edited you can check it out!  :D

Answer (score 1):

You may be a

> Cave

Yes I am Dark, Who am I?

> Caves are generally dark

I can roar but I have no mouth,

> These can me echoes from Animals

I can cry but I have no eyes,

> Again, echoes

I am good, but bad sometimes.

> Sometimes great things can be found inside caves, but dangerous animals can be there

And without me, you all die...

Two possible Explanations:

> It may explain that without the structural support, a cave can kill everyone inside by collapsing

OR

> It may suggest that caves may have been a vital part to human survival in the so called "Caveman ages"